# Custom UIModalPresentationStyle.custom: Why does presentationController(forPresented get called but not animationController(forPresented?

Tags: ios, swift, transition, uipresentationcontroller, uimodaltransitionstyle

I'm using `UIModalPresentationStyle.custom`.

In my `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` why does this method get called:

```
func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController?
```

But none of these functions get called:

```
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?

func interactionControllerForPresentation(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning?

func interactionControllerForDismissal(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set the `animated` Bool to `true` when calling

```
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I have the opposite problem—animationController() gets called, but not presentationController(). Mode is set to .custom. I'm completely stumped and losing my mind rapidly (well, since this is wasting hours of my time, I suppose it's not so rapid).